# WINSCP: task scheduler not working but is working when executed from winscp console?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ftp, scheduled-tasks, winscp

I have been trying to run a task scheduler named "Backup" that downloads the specified file from the FTP server to my local directory.

When I executed the command manually from the winscp console it worked but did not work in task scheduler. I have no errors shown but it gives a 0x1 code and in the history says

> Task Scheduler successfully finished "{152e054b-1562-4544-af06-d6c75f9e97b1}" instance of the "\Backup" task for user "domain\user".

The script action was:

```
Program/script: C:\Users\ID\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe
```

Add arguments (optional): `/command "winscp /script =C:\myScripts\testScript.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

The command-line arguments that you have specified do not make any sense.

It looks like you are trying instruct WinSCP to run WinSCP. That cannot work.

Use only this:

```
/script=C:\myScripts\testScript.txt
```

I.e. this is an equivalent to specifying the following full command on Windows command-line (you should test this before trying it from scheduler):

```
C:\Users\ID\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe /script=C:\myScripts\testScript.txt
```

See [WinSCP command-line documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline).